# Django admin panel does not display correctly

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

Good evening, I taught the django framework at the rate.
Before that, the admin panel was displayed correctly, now for some reason it is displayed as I understood without css styles
Default django server, writing code in pycharm

[image: wrong admin panel]

And before it was displayed like this
[image: correct admin panel]

**settings.py**

```html
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*ky(o6p+iw1(8u4fx$^fwnpdqt337(yw3*uk%g02b3*8(x-av$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # 'NAME': 'django',
        # 'USER': 'root',
        # 'PASSWORD': '',
        # 'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static'),
]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

**urls.py**

```html
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
                      path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
                  ] + urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Write, I will strip off any part of the code that you need

Please help get the old admin panel back!

Comment: In your browser console, check the network tab. Look for the static files requests and if they are successful or not.

Comment: How are you hosting your web-app?

Comment: the network tab
https://imgur.com/a/Vumyn6Y
Located at the standard django address 127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0):

From the image you posted in the comments, it does show that the files are indeed fetched and served — any `2xx` code is a success so it seems like something may be going wrong on the browser it-self.

If you haven't restarted the server to apply the static files then run the cmd `python manage.py collectstatic` to apply the changes and see if that solves the problem.

Try also opening in a different browser, and check whether if there are any error traces under the `Console tab`.

Have you made any changes in the `admin.py` file for the `.css` file (e.g. changed location or altered your project structure?). If your project is version controlled you can find the error by traversing through your previous commits.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible it is due to:

```
 DEBUG = False

 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Believe this helps:

1. While inside the project DIR, run:

   ```
   pip install whitenoise
   ```
2. Inside the settings.py file and under MIDDLEWARE, add:

   ```
   'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
   ```
3. Inside the settings.py file, add a file to collect static files. `productionfiles` is used as an example below:

   ```
   STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'productionfiles'
   STATIC_URL = 'static/'
   ```
4. While inside the project DIR again, run:

   ```
   py manage.py collectstatic
   ```
5. Finally, start the server:

   ```
   py manage.py runserver
   ```

NOTE: The command `py` is used for Windows. For Mac, use `python3` instead.